# What is the need of backup in Amazon RDS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have a doubt if in AWS all server-side work is done by cloud manager then why do we store backup for database?

I have studied in documentation that all the things are managed by cloud service providers for the database related things. Then what is the need of storing backup if service provider do everything for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You maintain your own backups of RDS instances for the same reason that you maintain offsite backups of on-premise databases: disaster recovery.  In your own data center, a fire or terrorism or natural disaster could destroy both your database and your local backups.  In the cloud, these disasters tend to take on a different form.

If all of your data is in any one place, then you are vulnerable to data loss in a catastrophic event, which could take a number of forms: a serious defect in the cloud provider's infrastructure (unlikely with AWS, but nothing is impossible), human error, malicious employees, a compromise of your credentials, or any other of a number of statistically-unlikely events -- the low probability of which becomes irrelevant when it occurs.

If you value your data, you back it up independently and outside of its native environment.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon RDS runs a database of your choice: MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, SQL Server. These are normal databases and operate in the same way as a database you would run yourself.

You are correct that a managed solution takes care of installation, maintenance and hardware issues. Also, you can configure the system to automatically take backups of the data.

From [Working With Backups - Amazon Relational Database Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_WorkingWithAutomatedBackups.html):

> Amazon RDS creates and saves **automated backups** of your DB instance. Amazon RDS creates a storage volume snapshot of your DB instance, backing up the entire DB instance and not just individual databases.
>
> Amazon RDS creates automated backups of your DB instance **during the backup window of your DB instance**. Amazon RDS saves the automated backups of your DB instance according to the backup retention period that you specify. If necessary, you can recover your database to any point in time during the backup retention period.

You also have the ability to trigger a **manual backup**. This is advisable, for example, before you do major work on the database, such as modifying schemas when upgrading an application that uses the database.

**Bottom line:** Amazon RDS can manage the backups for you. You do not need to take manage the backup process, but you can trigger the RDS backups yourself.

Comment: I have one more doubt . Is there any limit for the no of database and table in Amazon Aurora. I have read whole documentation but I didn't get the answer please clear my doubts

Comment: Data is only recoverable from backups, as described above and in the Amazon RDS documentation.

Comment: Thank you ... Please clear my second doubt I have asked in comment

Comment: I do not know about Aurora limits. You are welcome to create a new Question to ask this, rather than asking it as a comment on an existing question.